# How to individually/separately align child composables inside a Row?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, composable, android-compose-layout

I'm new in jetpack compose and I'm trying to do a simple thing that I can't achieve it.

That I want to do is in the same row align one component, in this case a surface, at the start and the other one, the column, at the end of the row.

How can get this?

I'm trying this but it doesn't work:

```
Row(Modifier.padding(top = 24.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.size(70.dp),
            shape = RectangleShape,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.2f)
        ) {
            // Image goes here
        }

        Column(modifier = Modifier.size(70.dp)) {
            Text("Total",
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                color = AppGreyDark,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 16.dp))

            Text("12,99 €",
                fontSize = 18.sp,
                color = AppBlackDark,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can apply in the `Row` the [**`Arrangement.SpaceBetween`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement#SpaceBetween()).

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
      .padding(top = 24.dp)
      .fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement  =  Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
       Surface()
       Column()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Won't work if the surface is wide enough to reach and overflow the column.

Comment: if I keep `Surface` gone, `Column` is coming to start place. how can I make `Column` not move from `End` alignment

Comment: what if surface width is too big? (for example it's Text instead of Surface and has long text), how to align it before Column without using Constraints?

Comment: @MohdQasim You hide the `Surface` left component based on some condition, right? use the same condition to set the  `horizontalArrangement` prop value

`horizontalArrangement = if (someCondition) Arrangement.SpaceBetween else Arrangement.End`